# fullCalendar + Bootstrap tabs glitch: not rendering events until resizing browser

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar

I'm having a strange problem when using **fullCalendar** along with **Bootstrap**, having the **calendar rendered within a non active tab pane**. I'm using the **AgendaView**, and it's initially displayed with the column for hours with just 1 pixel of width assigned to it.

It's placed within the "Operarios" tab.

But the biggest problem is when rendering the events. They all are displayed compressed at the top of the timetable.

Then if I resize the browser, or the frame, if I'm using Chrome Dev Tools or similar, then it's automatically re-rendered and it's correctly displayed.

You may check it out here:

https://codepen.io/luisapuyen/pen/RYXZPr

The HTML:

```js
+ function($) {
  $(function() {
    var opcionesCalendario = {
        selectable: true,
        unselectAuto: false,
        locale: 'es',
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        header: false,
        footer: false,
        height: 400,
        columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd',
        eventColor: '#ffdc11',
        views: {
          agenda: { // name of view
            titleFormat: '',
            allDaySlot: false,
            slotEventOverlap: false,
            minTime: '07:00:00',
            maxTime: '23:00:00',
            slotDuration: '01:00:00',
            footer: false
          }
        },
        select: function(startDate, endDate, event, view) {
          var evento = [{
            start: startDate,
            end: endDate
          }];
          $calendario.fullCalendar('addEventSource', evento);
          console.log('selected ' + startDate.format() + ' to ' + endDate.format(), view);
        }
      },
      $body = $('body'),
      $tabs = $body.find('#tabs-panel-autovisita'),
      $forms = $body.find('form'),
      $operariosSel = $forms.filter('[name="operarios"]').find('select[name="operarios"]')
    $calendario = $body.find('.calendario').fullCalendar(opcionesCalendario);

    // INICIO
    init();

    function init() {


      mostrarRangos();

      $operariosSel.on('change', function() {
        mostrarRangos();
      });
    }


    function obtenerDiaInicial() {
      return moment().isoWeekday(1);
    }


    function mostrarRangosOperarioCalendario(rangos) {
      var diaInicialMoment = obtenerDiaInicial(),
        diaMoment,
        diaSemana,
        eventos = [];
      $.each(rangos, function(i, rango) {
        diaSemana = +rango.dia_semana - 1;
        diaMoment = diaInicialMoment.clone().add(diaSemana, 'days');

        eventos.push({
          start: moment(diaMoment.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T' + rango.hora_inicio),
          end: moment(diaMoment.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T' + rango.hora_fin)
        });
      });

      $calendario.fullCalendar('removeEvents')
      $calendario.fullCalendar('renderEvents', eventos);

    }


    function obtenerRangosOperario(idOp) {
      // ajax request that returns:
      var res = JSON.parse('{"rangos":[{"dia_semana":"2","hora_inicio":"11:00:00","hora_fin":"13:00:00"},{"dia_semana":"1","hora_inicio":"09:00:00","hora_fin":"14:00:00"},{"dia_semana":"4","hora_inicio":"10:00:00","hora_fin":"17:00:00"},{"dia_semana":"3","hora_inicio":"14:00:00","hora_fin":"18:00:00"}],"ok":"1"}');
      mostrarRangosOperarioCalendario(res.rangos);
    }


    function mostrarRangos() {
      var idOp = +$operariosSel.val();
      obtenerRangosOperario(idOp);
    }
  });
}(jQuery);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <h3>Configuración Auto-visitas</h3>
      <nav>
        <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs-autovisita" role="tablist">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#general">General</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#operarios">Operarios</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#companyias">Compañías</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane show active" id="general" role="tabpanel">

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="operarios" role="tabpanel">
          <form method="post" name="operarios">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Operarios</label>
              <select name="operarios" class="form-control dato">
                <option value="0">Todos</option>

              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="calendario dato"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary guardar">Guardar</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="companyias" role="tabpanel">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure whether it's a bug produced when using fullCalendar and Bootstrap together.

The only way I've found it works is having the calendar in the active pane at first. But since semantically it corresponds to the first tab to be the one which must be active, I'd like to find a better solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fullcalendar is failing to retrieve sizes and dimensions of elements because they are set to `display: none`. You can see that from computed styles on page refresh. Your events are supposed to have a `top` and `bottom` set but instead they receive a value of `0` for both.

[image]

This is why your events are all "displayed compressed at the top of the timetable".

A simple fix is to listen for a tab change event and re-render fullcalendar.

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
    $calendario.fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
});
```

Here's a [functioning example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KxOQrw?editors=1010).

Comment: hello, this is not working for me, i got a shrinked calendar with not all the functionnalities with the following code (materialize tabs) : 
`$('.tabs li').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var baseURL = window.location.origin;
   var url = $(this).children().first().attr('href');
   window.location.href = baseURL+"/main" + url;
   if (url == "#calendar") {
     //calendar.render();
     calendar.rerenderEvents();
   }
 })`

Answer (score 0):

In React fullcalendar (version 5), I could not call the render or rerender method.

FullCalendar automatically updates size if it listens to window resize events. I just the trigger resize event when the calendar tab is visible with some delay.
Refer following code

```
setTimeout(() => window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')), 500)
```